# How to send 3mb data URL with ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, canvas

I need to pass a huge set of data with jquery ajax - image data. In which I can't use the usual way of uploading. Because the image data is from a canvas - [literalycanvas](http://literallycanvas.com/examples/imgur.html). I've tried sent it but it's not get through. The data sample as follow: (pink is image data which is a lot longer than this and yellow is a truncate warning)

[image]

Well, I need to pass this data along the jquery ajax. So

1. Is there any possibility to do?
2. Can I write it to a cookie instead?
3. Can I pass it through the session?

Here's my code :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'print.php',
        type: 'POST',

        data: {
          // convert the image data to base64
          filename:'<?=$_GET[file]?>',//photo/2015-03-09/img_00215.jpg
          image:  lc.canvasForExport().toDataURL().split(',')[1],
          type: 'base64'
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.export_btn').html("<div class=\"alert alert-success\"><i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> Printed</div>");
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.export_btn').html("<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><i class=\"fa fa-warning\"></i> Print error!</div>");
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

As you can see, the **image:** is sending a long line of data. Which is needs to send along the data. Any idea I can send this?

Comment: Since you're sending this to PHP, have you tried increasing the `post_max_size` directive?

Comment: currently `post_max_size = 8M` and I've changed it to `32` now, and still not work. Any idea?

Comment: but what is the problem? it simply freezes or what? What callback is executed in the end?

Comment: Your error message appears to reflect a limit of what Firebug is willing to display. Do you have any other error messages on the server or client, related to the actual submission?

Comment: @skip405 the problem is it cannot send the data to the process file. It's not freeze. The callback is to save that data into a file on a hard drive.

Comment: @apsillers, the program itself doesn't shows any error but just not work.

Comment: As the original source here : http://literallycanvas.com/examples/imgur.html. There's another line of `headers:{      Accept:'application/json'}` too. Do I have to send it with json?

Comment: does your `print.php` `echo` anything? You expect some `data` in the `success` callback. What is it?

Comment: @skip405, when I skip sending `image` with the data. I can see everything with `print_r($_POST)` - `filename` and `type`. But when I include `image` with the sending. It shows nothing - likely it cannot sent. I don't want any callback from `print.php`. Just process from the `print.php` itself.